# Performing class method directly on the output of a function that returns data in that class (C++)

Tags: c++, methods

I'm brand new to all of this, and I'm sure I'm not quite phrasing things properly - sorry about any dumb questions and mistakes, and thanks for bearing with me! :)

That aside, here's my situation: I've created a class, a member function for that class, and another (non-member) function that returns values in that class. I know that everything works the way it's supposed to on its own - the member function returns the expected values when I use it on normal objects, and the other function returns the objects that it's supposed to - but for some reason I don't seem to get anything at all when I use them this way:

```
functionReturningMyObject(parameters).memberFunction(other parameters);
```

Is there no way to get a method to act directly on an object that is the output of another function in this way? Or does my problem lie elsewhere?

**EDIT**: here is my attempt at a "minimal reproducible example," as requested:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mre.hpp"

//Here are some objects
Class first (1, 'A');
Class second (1, 'B');
Class third (2, 'A');
Class fourth (2, 'D');

//Here is the function returning objects in the class
Class FindMatchingObject(int matchNumber, char matchLetter) {
  if ((first.getNumber()==matchNumber)&&(first.getLetter()==matchLetter)) {
    return first;
  }
  else if ((second.getNumber()==matchNumber)&&(second.getLetter()==matchLetter)) {
    return second;
  }
  else if ((third.getNumber()==matchNumber)&&(third.getLetter()==matchLetter)) {
    return third;
  }
  else if ((fourth.getNumber()==matchNumber)&&(fourth.getLetter()==matchLetter)) {
    return fourth;
  }
}

int main() {

   //User puts in a string consisting of: first, the old number-letter pair to identify the object they'd like to change, then second, the new number-letter pair that they'd like to change it to. In this case, I put in '1B8H' to pick 'second' and change its values to 8 and H.
  std::string userInput;
  std::cin >> userInput;
  int oldUserNumber = userInput[0] - 48;
  char oldUserLetter = userInput[1];
  int newUserNumber = userInput[2] - 48;
  char newUserLetter = userInput[3];

  //Here we see that, indeed, 'second' is being identified by the function.
  std::cout << FindMatchingObject(oldUserNumber, oldUserLetter).getNumber() << FindMatchingObject(oldUserNumber, oldUserLetter).getLetter() << "\n";

  // Here we see that, indeed, the change() method can take an object and set new values for it.
  third.change(7, 'G');
  std::cout << third.getNumber() << third.getLetter() << "\n";

  // But here, after trying to use change() on 'second' directly through the FindMatchingObject() function, the values of the object remain unchanged afterwards.
  FindMatchingObject(oldUserNumber, oldUserLetter).change(newUserNumber, newUserLetter);
  std::cout << second.getNumber() << second.getLetter() << "\n";
}
```

mre.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Class {
  char letter;
  int number;

  public:
  Class(int number0, char letter0);
  void change(int newNumber, char newLetter);
  int getNumber();
  char getLetter();
};
```

mre.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mre.hpp"

Class::Class(int number0, char letter0) {
  number=number0;
  letter=letter0;
}

void Class::change(int newNumber, char newLetter) {
  number=newNumber;
  letter=newLetter;
}

int Class::getNumber() {
  return number;
}

char Class::getLetter() {
  return letter;
}
```

Also, I know it's kind of gross having all of that stuff above the main() function, but for some reason I got compiling errors until I put them there.

Comment: Please post an actual [mre] instead of a vague description of the code

Comment: Sounds like a lifetime problem, but we cannot really say anything without actual code that has an issue.

Comment: Oh, okay -- I'm sorry! I've looked at the link, and will edit it now and try to include adequate information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FindMatchingObject()` function returns a `Class` object by value, thus returning a *copy* of the object. So, you are calling `change()` on a copy of `second`, not on `second` itself.  That is why `second` doesn’t change, even though `second` was returned.

To fix that, your function would have to return a `Class` object by reference or pointer instead.

However, do note that your function has *undefined behavior* if no matching object is found, as no `return` gets executed in that case. Your compiler should be warning you about that.  You would need to either return a default object, or throw an exception, or return `nullptr` if you change the function to return a `Class*` pointer.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's interesting and useful to know -- I had no idea that returning a value meant returning a copy...

Comment: Erm, sorry -- I meant to put this in the above comment but didn't know that you had to use shift+enter. For some reason, I don't seem to be able to make the pointer function work. Could you point me to any good resources? I looked at some examples, but I keep getting a compiler error like "cannot convert 'Class' to 'Class*' in return".

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out -- thanks again! :)